# Adding manual approval stage in CDK CodePipelines

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline

I have been working with AWS CDK and I think its a great way to work with AWS. Recently I have got a problem which I am unable to resolve. Went over documentations and resources but none had explained how to do it in CDK. So I have two code pipelines and each pipeline either deploys to staging or production. Now I want a manual approval stage before the code gets deployed to production. I'll show my simple code below for reference:

```
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { AppsPluginsCdkStack } from './apps-plugins-services/stack';
import {
  CodePipeline,
  ShellStep,
  CodePipelineSource
} from '@aws-cdk/pipelines';

class ApplicationStage extends cdk.Stage {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);
    new CdkStack(this, 'cdkStack');
  }
}

class ProductionPipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);

    //Create the CDK Production Pipeline
    const prodPipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'ProductionPipeline', {
      pipelineName: 'ProdPipeline',
      synth: new ShellStep('ProdSynth', {
        // Use a connection created using the AWS console to authenticate to GitHub
        input: CodePipelineSource.connection(
          'fahigm/cdk-repo',
          'develop',
          {
            connectionArn:
              'AWS-CONNECTION-ARN' // Created using the AWS console
          }
        ),
        commands: ['npm ci', 'npm run build', 'npx cdk synth']
      })
    });

    prodPipeline.addStage(new ApplicationStage(this, 'Production'));
  }
}

class StagingPipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    //Create the CDK Staging Pipeline
    const stagePipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'StagingPipeline', {
      pipelineName: 'StagePipeline',
      synth: new ShellStep('StageSynth', {
        // Use a connection created using the AWS console to authenticate to GitHub
        input: CodePipelineSource.connection(
          'fahigm/cdk-repo',
          'master',
          {
            connectionArn:
              'AWS-CONNECTION-ARN' // Created using the AWS console
          }
        ),
        commands: ['npm ci', 'npm run build', 'npx cdk synth']
      })
    });

    stagePipeline.addStage(new ApplicationStage(this, 'Staging'));
  }
}
//
const app = new cdk.App();

new ProductionPipelineStack(app, 'ProductionCDKPipeline', {
  env: { account: 'ACCOUNT', region: 'REGION' }
});

new StagingPipelineStack(app, 'StagingCDKPipeline', {
  env: { account: 'ACCOUNT', region: 'REGION' }
});

app.synth();
```

Now I don't know where to go from here. The documentation only talks about how to do it from console but I want to add it in the code. Would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Why not a single pipeline with two stages?

Comment: @gshpychka well i saw an answer or a blog where they were doing it this way to setup a pipeline for each stage. But is there a benefit in having a single pipeline?

Comment: The benefit is that it's sequential, and production comes after staging. But you'll have to do it with a single git branch, can't do it with multiple. Accept the answer if it answers the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CDK documentation doesn't actually talk about how to do it from console, it talks about how to do it with CDK, and provides examples. Here's an example [straight from the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/pipelines-readme.html#validation):

> The following example shows both an automated approval in the form of a ShellStep, and a manual approval in the form of a ManualApprovalStep added to the pipeline. Both must pass in order to promote from the PreProd to the Prod environment:

```js
declare const pipeline: pipelines.CodePipeline;
const preprod = new MyApplicationStage(this, 'PreProd');
const prod = new MyApplicationStage(this, 'Prod');

pipeline.addStage(preprod, {
  post: [
    new pipelines.ShellStep('Validate Endpoint', {
      commands: ['curl -Ssf https://my.webservice.com/'],
    }),
  ],
});
pipeline.addStage(prod, {
  pre: [
    new pipelines.ManualApprovalStep('PromoteToProd'),
  ],
});
```

Here's the documentation about the manual approval step specifically: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_pipelines.ManualApprovalStep.html

Comment: is there also a possibility to add emails where the notification will be sent to approve?

Comment: Yeah, you can publish notifications to an SNS topic, and you can do anything you need with that, including sending emails.

Comment: When we click on the button for approval, it opens up a dialogue with fields like Comment and Url for review. Now I can pass the comment because that is an optional field, but there is no field to pass in the url. Am i missing something?

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to. Consult the documentation and open a new question if you don't find a solution.

Comment: @gshpychka are you able to send email notification on manual approval in cdk pipeline ??